# jQuery Validation - Run when errors are fixed

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I run some custom code when I validate to show a box indicating there are errors. I run this in the invalidHandler.

Is there a way to run code when all errors are satisfied before submittal?

Thanks,
- Vince

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options):

> **submitHandler**
>   Callback for handling the actual submit when the form is valid.

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        // do other stuff for a valid form
        form.submit();
    }
})
```